# How to expand partition into free space that lies before it

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I would like to expand my "journal" partition to include the free space that lies (logically) before it on the drive. How can I do this without losing the data in "journal".

[image]

I have a few more iterations to go through but I'm eventually going to move everything on the NTFS partition into journal, but I have to keep moving and expending/shrinking to make enough room.

Comment: This is the type of task I'd always give to iPartition, however the current release is not fully Yosemite-ready & doesn't like core storage drives - see https://coriolis-systems.com/support/2015/3/using-ipartition-345-yosemite

Comment: i don't know if this makes a difference or not, but this is all on an external USB drive

Comment: @TruthOf42 Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/diskx` with x = disk identifier of your external USB-drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are asking, per se.  What you would have to do is create new partition "above" your existing partition, copy the data there, kill the partition below, then expand the partition with the data into the newly created free space.

You can do this with  [Disk Utility](http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/20/resize-partitions-in-mac-os-x-with-disk-utility/).  OS X Daily has a really good write up on it (limited on how to resize the partition)

***However***, I am personally not a fan of resizing disks with any sort of data on it.

I prefer to follow these steps:

- Copy all data from the drive to my desktop, a USB, burn a DVD;
  basically make a backup copy of the drive.
- Using Disk Utility, erase and repartition the drive.
- Copy data back to the drive.

Yes, it's a bit old school, but it is super reliable (not that the partition resizing is a failure by any means).  I am just old school and this procedure gives me peace of mind.

Comment: The task mentioned in the link of your answer doesn't show "backwards" expanding a partition. In fact it's not possible to move the beginning of a partition to lower sector numbers with Disk Utility. Please adjust your answer!

Comment: @klanomath.  Good catch...